# Get element that triggered event?

Tags: java, events, scope

I have multiple fields with **bank-name** class. Initially there is only one bank field available, though user can add more. I want to add `ChangeListener` to `TextField` to change text on focus lost. How can I address `this` (`TextField` that triggered event) in my code?
My code is:

```
bankContainer.lookup(".bank-name").focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue,
            Boolean newPropertyValue) {
        if (!newPropertyValue) {
            System.out.println(this);
            trimText(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParentClass.this`, which accesses the parent class instance.
(Just replace `ParentClass` with the actual parent class name.)